# Retrieving coordinates from geoJSON multidimentional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, geojson

I'm pulling my hair out what's left of it. I need to get the coordinates and geofence type (in this case Polygon) from a geoJSON array. Below is what I have. Thanks in advance. 
Larry.

```
$str='{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.0416259765625,38.89530825492018],[-77.03295707702638,38.89351294034218],[-77.03700184822084,38.89317057287496],[-77.0323669910431,38.892193563954955],[-77.04053163528442,38.89286160569515],[-77.0416259765625,38.89530825492018]]]}}]}';

$json = json_decode($str);
echo'<pre>';print_r($json);echo'</pre>';
$set = 1;
foreach($json->type->geometry->coordinates[0] as $coordinates)
{
    echo 'Set '.$set.': ';$set++;
    echo $coordinates[0].','.$coordinates[1].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: When you're stuck, you can 1: `print_r` the structure; 2: incrementally `print_r` the access. Since you already tried step 1, you could try adding each level to the `print_r`, like so: `print_r($json);`, then `print_r($json->features);`, then `print_r($json->features[0]);` and so on..

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully that will help especially in the case of an array having multiple geofences.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's only ever one "feature", just change your `foreach` loop to:

```
foreach($json->features[0]->geometry->coordinates[0] as $coordinates)
```

Full working code:

```
<?php
$str='{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.0416259765625,38.89530825492018],[-77.03295707702638,38.89351294034218],[-77.03700184822084,38.89317057287496],[-77.0323669910431,38.892193563954955],[-77.04053163528442,38.89286160569515],[-77.0416259765625,38.89530825492018]]]}}]}';

$json = json_decode($str);
// echo'<pre>';print_r($json);echo'</pre>';
$set = 1;
foreach($json->features[0]->geometry->coordinates[0] as $coordinates)
{
    echo 'Set '.$set.': ';$set++;
    echo $coordinates[0].','.$coordinates[1]."<br>\n";
}

// Output:

// Set 1: -77.041625976562,38.89530825492<br>
// Set 2: -77.032957077026,38.893512940342<br>
// Set 3: -77.037001848221,38.893170572875<br>
// Set 4: -77.032366991043,38.892193563955<br>
// Set 5: -77.040531635284,38.892861605695<br>
// Set 6: -77.041625976562,38.89530825492<br>
?>
```